# Segfaulting when trying to parse with lxml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have this simple python script which goes like this:

```
import sys 
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('gdpdefl.xml')
```

But it segfaults, so, after some googling, I figured my xml document might be broken, so I tried this:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse('gdpdefl.xml', parser)
```

This also segfaulted. Here's a sample of the xml document I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Root xmlns:wb="http://www.worldbank.org">   <data>
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="ARB">Arab World</field>
      <field name="Item" key="NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG">Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)</field>
      <field name="Year">1960</field>
      <field name="Value" />
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="ARB">Arab World</field>
      <field name="Item" key="NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG">Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)</field>
      <field name="Year">1961</field>
      <field name="Value" />
    </record> 
    <record>
      <field name="Country or Area" key="ZWE">Zimbabwe</field>
      <field name="Item" key="NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG">Inflation, GDP deflator (annual %)</field>
      <field name="Year">2011</field>
      <field name="Value">21.1562931758805</field>
    </record>
  </data>
</Root>
```

If I do have badly formed xml here, what would be the best way to get all the Country, Item, Year and Values strings out of this file and into lists?

Comment: Works for me with no segfault in Python 2.7.3 under Ubuntu. Does `python -c 'print "ok"'` work? What else could be relevant, such as your `python --version`?

Comment: I'm working on a remote Red Hat system so I don't have control of the version number but they have modules for both python 2.6.5 and python 2.7.2, for 2.6.5 they don't have an lxml module. I think I might just end up defining an HTMLParser class and then feeding my docs in line by line, thanks for the advice though!